# Playback from FFMPEG x265 freezes video but not audio

Tags: ffmpeg, playback, vlc

So I am re-encoding an old AVI:
https://pastebin.com/KqcHMVAx

I have written a batch to re-encode a bunch of similar AVI's and the same problem occurs with each.
When I try and play the resulting MKV in VLC the video freezes after a few seconds, but the audio continues. I get the following VLC messages:

> avcodec info: Using D3D11VA (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080, vendor 10de(NVIDIA), device 1b80, revision a1) for hardware decoding
> avcodec error: hardware acceleration picture allocation failed
> avcodec error: avcodec_send_packet critical error

My FFMpeg arguments are as follows:

```
-y -i "{0}" -c:v libx265 -crf 23 -preset slow -tune fastdecode -c:a copy -x265-params "colorprim=5:transfer=1:colormatrix=6:refine-mv=1" "{1}"
```

Which results in: https://pastebin.com/VTstcKF7

If I repeat the same encoding in Handbrake, the playback is fine, no problems. That results in: https://pastebin.com/v3ix1caA

Now I've compared the two and the only difference in the encoding settings is

```
frame-threads=3 instead of 2 in my batch
numa-pools=4 appears in my batch but not Handbrake
refine-mv=1 instead of 0 in my batch.
```

To clarify my FFMPEG sets frame-threads to 2, numa-pools to 4 and refine-mv to 0. I have set the refine-mv to 1 but it seems to have been ignored.

Now I am running handbrake on Linux with x265 version 3.2.1+1 and the batch is running under Windows with version 3.1+19.

I have tried running FFMpeg on the Linux machine with the same settings, same result in failure.

I've mirrored the settings as close as I can to Handbrake but I cannot seem to achieve a file free of issues. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What happens with ffplay?

Comment: FFPlay seems to work just fine. And the Windows inbuilt Media player plays it fine. I was initially going to submit this as a VLC bug, but the internet had compression options suggestions. So I decided to do a comparison with Handbrake. And as you can see the same settings with Handbrake produce an error free file. I am assuming it's a parameter/setting I'm not including rather than an FFMpeg bug.